# To set Swagger Json path

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I have a requirement to set the `swagger.json` file path as below in QA environment:

`https://api-qa.com/epservice/swagger/v1/swagger.json`

For that, this is the code I have provided in the `configure()` method in the `Startup.cs` file:

```csharp
string swaggerBasePath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SERVICE_NAME");
string apiVersion = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("API_VERSION");
app.UseSwagger(c =>
        {
            c.PreSerializeFilters.Add((swagger, httpReq) =>
            {                   
                swagger.Servers = new List<OpenApiServer> { new OpenApiServer { Url = $"https://{httpReq.Host.Value}/{swaggerBasePath}/{apiVersion}" } };
            });                
        });
        
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint($"{swaggerBasePath}/swagger/v1/swagger.json", $"API {apiVersion}");
            
        });
```

And value for the environment variable `SERVICE_NAME="epservice"` and `API_VERSION="v1"`

But when I try this I am getting fetch error with below wrong path:

> Fetch error
> Not Found https://api-qa.com/epservice/swagger/epservice/swagger/v1/swagger.json

Issue is showing `epservice/swagger` twice in the path.

Comment: did you add services.AddSwaggerGen() into ConfigureServices() method?

Comment: "Issue is showing epservice/swagger twice in the path.", try to set a break point in the configure method and check whether the swaggerBasePath show the `epservice/swagger` twice? If it has two `epservice/swagger`, try to change the value, if it only has one `epservice/swagger`, try to remove the swaggerBasePath, the updated code like this: `c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", $"API {apiVersion}");`.

Comment: Try solution in the comments above.
Also, you can try to change url in `PreSerializeFilters` ->
`Url = $"{request.Scheme}://{request.Host.Value}{request.Headers["X-Forwarded-Prefix"].FirstOrDefault()}"`